# How to remove prime node in linked list?

Tags: c++

can anyone help me to make function in this code to delete prime numbers in linked list
here ?
and another function in this code to return middle element in this linked list?...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class node
{
public:
    int data;
    node*next;
};
class list
{
public:
    node * head;
    list()
    {
        head=NULL;
    }
    void insertfirst(int d)
    {
        node * x=new node;
        x->data=d;
        x->next=NULL;
        if(head==NULL)
            head=x;
        else
        {
            x->next=head;
            head=x;
        }
    }
    void deletefirst()
    {
        if (head==NULL)
            cout<<"Empty";
        else
        {
            node *b=head;
            head=b->next;
            delete b;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        node *p=head;
        while (p!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<p->data << " ";
            p=p->next;
        }
    }
   
};
int main()
{
    list s;
    s.insertlast(6);
    s.insertfirst(37);
    s.deletefirst();
    s.print();
}
```

Comment: First you make an `bool isPrime(int num)` function. I don't see that in your code. Then you traverse the list and delete the node when `isPrime(current->data)` returns true.

Comment: you can write this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
bool isPrime(int num){
   for(int i = 2; i <= num; i++){
      if(i == num){
         return true;
       }else if(num % i == 0){
         return false;
       }
   }return false;
}

void deletefirst()
{
    if (head==NULL)
        cout<<"Empty";
    else
    {
       node *b=head;
       if(isPrime(b->data)){
          head=b->next;
          delete b;
       }else{
          cout<<"is Prime";
       }
       
    }
}
```